# CANT GET VALUE FROM ENTRY

Tags: python-3.x

I'm attempting to develop a registration form, but I can't get the value of the entries because nonetype and return self func are specified.

I tried entering values into the entries, but nothing worked. Again, we find that understanding some of the features and structure of your code is required before you can make modifications.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class App():
    # created window
    # made all entries global
    ##################################################### ENTRIES #####################################################################

    # some entries
    def submit():
        MsgBox = messagebox.askokcancel('FYEF',"stuff",icon = 'info')
        if MsgBox == True:
            # ENTRIES
            enroll = enroll_code.get()
            readonly = readonly_combo.get()
            school = schools.get()
            sc_did = sc_id.get()
            sc_dd = sc_add.get()
            vr = vrb.get()
            if vr == 1:
                vr = 'Private'
            elif vrb == 2:
                vr = 'Public'
            PSA = PSA_no.get()
            lr_no = lr_number.get()
            last_nme = last_name.get()
            first_nme = first_name.get()
            mid_nme = mid_name.get()
            ext_nme = ext_name.get()
            birth_dte = birth_date.get()
            ageyr = age.get()
            vhr = vhar.get()
            if vhr == 1:
                vhr = 'Male'
            elif vhr == 2:
                vhr = 'Female'
            iic = ip_ic.get()
            if iic == 1:
                iic = 'Yes'
            elif iic == 2:
                iic = 'No'
            mother_ton = mother_tongue.get()
            relgaff = relg_aff.get()
            spneeds = sp_needs.get()
            eadd = em_add.get()
            hom_add = home_add.get()
            f_name = fath_name.get()
            f_contact = fath_contact.get()
            m_name = moth_name.get()
            m_contact = moth_contact.get()
            g_name = guar_name.get()
            g_contact = guar_contact.get()
            m_wifi = means_wifi.get()
            p_modal = pref_modal.get()
            concern = concerns.get()
            approve = approval.get()
            tday = date.today()
            dte = today.strftime("%B %d, %Y")

            woot = tk.Tk()
            wlc = ttk.Label(woot, text='Welcome!', font='bold, 30').place(x=50,y=100)

            
    # SUBMIT Button
    submit_button = ttk.Button(tab_2, text="Submit", command=submit).place(x=655,y=700)
App()
```

Comment: You dont show how the entries are made, so does this answer your question? [Tkinter: AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute <attribute name>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Asked by Delrius Euphoria. The woot = tk.Tk(), app = App(), and woot.mainloop() should be outside of class . ttk.Label should be outside of function

Try this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

woot = tk.Tk()
class App():
    # created window
    # made all entries global
    ##################################################### ENTRIES #####################################################################

    # some entries
    def submit():
        MsgBox = messagebox.askokcancel('FYEF',"stuff",icon = 'info')
        if MsgBox == True:
            # ENTRIES
            enroll = enroll_code.get()
            readonly = readonly_combo.get()
            school = schools.get()
            sc_did = sc_id.get()
            sc_dd = sc_add.get()
            vr = vrb.get()
            if vr == 1:
                vr = 'Private'
            elif vrb == 2:
                vr = 'Public'
            PSA = PSA_no.get()
            lr_no = lr_number.get()
            last_nme = last_name.get()
            first_nme = first_name.get()
            mid_nme = mid_name.get()
            ext_nme = ext_name.get()
            birth_dte = birth_date.get()
            ageyr = age.get()
            vhr = vhar.get()
            if vhr == 1:
                vhr = 'Male'
            elif vhr == 2:
                vhr = 'Female'
            iic = ip_ic.get()
            if iic == 1:
                iic = 'Yes'
            elif iic == 2:
                iic = 'No'
            mother_ton = mother_tongue.get()
            relgaff = relg_aff.get()
            spneeds = sp_needs.get()
            eadd = em_add.get()
            hom_add = home_add.get()
            f_name = fath_name.get()
            f_contact = fath_contact.get()
            m_name = moth_name.get()
            m_contact = moth_contact.get()
            g_name = guar_name.get()
            g_contact = guar_contact.get()
            m_wifi = means_wifi.get()
            p_modal = pref_modal.get()
            concern = concerns.get()
            approve = approval.get()
            tday = date.today()
            dte = today.strftime("%B %d, %Y")

 
    wlc = ttk.Label(woot, text='Welcome!', font='bold, 30').place(x=50,y=100)
    enroll_code =ttk.Entry(woot).place(x=50,y=150)

    # SUBMIT Button
    submit_button = ttk.Button(woot, text="Submit", command=submit).place(x=655,y=700)
          
app = App()
woot.mainloop()
```

Comment: What changes did you make? How is this different from the OP's question and why does this work ~ A good answer often answers these questions primarily

Comment: The woot = tk.Tk(), app = App(), and  woot.mainloop() should be outside of class . ttk.Label should be outside of function.

Comment: Cool, but these have to explained in your answer and not in the comments